# Can iOS URL support unicode characters within top level domain?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, tld

I'm building an iOS app that takes urls as input.
Unicode characters are valid for a tld but when I instantiate a valid URL that contains unicode characters NSURL returns nil.
Is this even possible?
swift eg.

`URL(string: "http://➡.ws/䨹")`

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to use special characters in URL **(Swift 3)** :

```
let myUrl = "http://➡.ws/䨹" as String
let url = URL(string: myUrl) // nil here .. problem !
if let encoded = myUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed){
    let urlencoded = URL(string: encoded) // "http://%E2%9E%A1.ws/%E4%A8%B9" here :) no problem ^^
}
```

Comment: This is not correct because you need to encode the host name using Punycode (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3492) instead of the percent encoding.

Comment: When i copy "http://%E2%9E%A1.ws/%E4%A8%B9" and past in Safari, it works.

Comment: FYI: This answer fails on iOS these days and only works in Safari/Mac because Safari itself knows how to encode to punycode. See http://openradar.appspot.com/6923664 for more info.